# Why are solar panels still efficient with cloudy weather?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Recently I did an experiment in college involving solar panels.
I noticed that the weather suddenly changed from sunny to cloudy, however the output of the solar panels dropped only very little.
My guess is that light with shorter wavelength (e.g. UV-light) passes through the clouds better and doesn't lose much of his intensity.
Then again I'm not an expert on this topic, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've read that the power output of solar panels can drop by a factor of about 4 to 10 in going from a sunny day to a cloudy one. Were you really measuring the power output of the panels, or were you simply measuring the no-load voltage output of the solar panels?

Comment: Nice interactive graph at https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/effect-of-light-intensity . Notice how the open circuit voltage of the cell (i.e., the place where the red line meets the horizontal "Voltage" axis), shifts very little as you move the "concentration of light..." slider, whereas the "current density" in the cell varies quite a lot. I don't really understand how the current density within the cell relates to its ability to produce power, but I'm pretty sure it's important.